# Which wake-up trigger states are available on Movesense's MAX3000x?

Tags: movesense

Movesense allows to set up waking up from a heartbeat via `/Component/MAX3000x/WakeUp`. But I couldn't find what `uint8` values are available and what they mean. I've found only `1` used in some examples to "prepare AFE to wake-up mode."

Are there any other valid values? If so, what do they mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0 = disabled

1 = wake on studs (ULP_LON in datasheet) enabled

No other values are available

*Full disclaimer: I work for the Movesense team*

Answer (score 1):

For those looking for other ways to wake up the sensor, you can also use the LSM6DS3 to trigger wake-up on movement. Put it to sleep with the following code:

```
#include "component_lsm6ds3/resources.h"

...

// Prepare  wake-up mode
WB_RES::WakeUpState wakeupState;

/* Example sensitivity levels (pick one or adjust yourself) */
wakeupState.level = 1; // Triggers when simply picked up
wakeupState.level = 50; // Triggers with forceful movement

wakeupState.state = 1; // Value for Movement
asyncPut(WB_RES::LOCAL::COMPONENT_LSM6DS3_WAKEUP(),
        AsyncRequestOptions::ForceAsync, wakeupState);

// Make PUT request to enter power off mode
asyncPut(WB_RES::LOCAL::SYSTEM_MODE(), AsyncRequestOptions::ForceAsync,
        WB_RES::SystemModeValues::FULLPOWEROFF);`
```

This example can be found in the documentation for [movement_wakeup](https://www.movesense.com/docs/esw/sample_applications/#movement-wakeup) and the example project by the same name.